# Symfony2 can't find jquery.js file in components

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony

I am trying to follow this tutorial to install bootstraps in symfony2: https://coderwall.com/p/kzyiaw

When I run this command from terminal: php app/console assetic:dump --force

I get this error:

```
17:46:25 [file+] /var/www/html/learn-symfony/app/../web/js/06837fc_part_1.js

  [RuntimeException]                                                                                      
  The source file "/var/www/html/learn-symfony/app/Resources/public/js/vendor/jquery.js" does not exist.
```

In composer.json, I have the jquery installed in the components directory:

```
"require": {
    ...............
    "components/jquery": "*"
}
```

I can find the directory and the jquery file from route/components but composer is looking in the wrong folder. In config.yml, I have this under assetic configuration:

```
 assets:
    jquery_js:
        inputs:
           - '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/public/js/vendor/jquery.js'
```

In the Resources directory under the app, the only folders that exist are java and views.

What should I be changing in order for composer find the jquery.js file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Composer doesn't need to find the file, Assetic needs to find it.

I currently use jquery loaded with components/jquery and have the assetic set up like so..

```
assetic:
    ... debug, filters, etc ...
    assets:
        jquery: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/jquery/jquery.min.js
        underscore: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/underscore/underscore-min.js
        and so on...
```

This is loading the file with the source as the components/jquery folder in the vendor directory.

Comment: *Comment posted as answer from [Finlay Beaton](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4565094/finlay-beaton):* It should be noticed from the above solution, that you don't need to define a 'named asset' in config.yml, you can just use `%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/jquery/jquery.min.js` in your assetic stylesheet or css. This is important for css as the cssrewrite cannot use the `@named_asset` notation.